# LINQ2SQL: Join multiple tables

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, asp.net-mvc-2

I'm not that good at linq2sql or even sql, but everything comes with a little training.

My question:
i got 3 tables:
Projects,
Folders and
Tasks.

I need to make the query so that i join these 3 tables.

I've tried a bit:

```
public ActionResult Details(string id) {
        var user = GetProfile().Id;
        var p = _db.Projects.Where(x => Convert.ToString(x.ProjectId) == id && x.UserId == user).SingleOrDefault();
        var f = _db.Folders.Where(x => x.ProjectId == p.ProjectId).ToList();
        return View(f);
    }
```

This works fine, and i get the folders related to the project. Now i want, in the same query the tasks, who is related to the folders and the project.

So at the end i get this scenario:
Click's on a projectname, sends the ID, takes the ID, and presents the folders related to the project i clicked on and presents the tasks on the same site as the folders.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not completely sure on what you're trying to accomplish exactly here. But here is a linq to sql query where I am joining projects onto folders and folders onto tasks. Project has a field named ProjectId and Folders also has a "ProjectId" in which I'm joining on. Folders will have a "FolderId" and tasks will also have a "FolderId", assuming the same naming convention. Hope it helps:

```
var result = (from projects in _db.Projects
                      join folders in _db.Folders
                      on projects.ProjectId equals folders.ProjectId
                      join tasks in _db.Tasks
                      on folders.FolderId equals tasks.FolderId
                      where projects.Id.ToString() == id
                      && projects.UserId == user
                      select projects).ToList();
```

result will represent a list of Projects that match the criteria.

Comment: Note: this is for inner joins. if you want to do a left outter join, i'll show you that as well

Comment: That was the right answer I was looking for! I'm sorry for the bad explanation, but i'm glad you understood it! Thanks!

Comment: please could you show how to do this query using Lambda syntax (if possible) ?

Comment: Lambda syntax (method syntax) is a bit more tricky for me, I believe something like this will get you started off on just joining the projects onto the folders... Though I'm not real sure: 

            var result = projects.Where(p => p.Id.ToString() == id && projects.UserId == user)
                .Join(folders, p => p.ProjectId, f => f.ProjectId,
                (p, f) => new Project { declare all project references here with p.* }).ToList();

Here's a link that may be helpful http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/linqtosql/thread/42ffd0ac-42dd-41df-9fc9-d87d41ede7ba

Answer (score 1):

I'm no expert in converting SQL to Linq, but in the spirit of suggesting a tool that you can use over and over in order to convert complex SQL Queries over to LINQ, maybe you can check out

### Linqer